# Adding multiple iframes with different sources in javascript

Tags: javascript, iframe

I want to make a page that shows all images from Mars Insight.
How can i make it repeat itself so its generating more iframes with new images? The image files are numbered 12 and so on, at the moment its only showing 1 image.

```
var insightFeed = {
    url: "https://mars.nasa.gov/raw_images/embed/",
    file: 12,
    showImage: function() {
        window.onload = function() {
            var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.style.display = "block";
            iframe.style.height = "420px";
            iframe.style.width = "400px";
            iframe.style.border = "none";
            iframe.src = insightFeed.url + (insightFeed.file);
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }
    }
};
insightFeed.showImage();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i make it repeat itself so its generating more iframes with new images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the numbers aren't sequential (like 1 to 20) you're gonna have to punch them in. I rewrote your code so you can do this:

```
var insightFeed = {
  url: "https://mars.nasa.gov/raw_images/embed/",
  showImage: function(image) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.style.display = "block";
    iframe.style.height = "420px";
    iframe.style.width = "400px";
    iframe.style.border = "none";
    iframe.src = insightFeed.url + (image);
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  insightFeed.showImage(12);
  insightFeed.showImage(13);
  insightFeed.showImage(14);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this can be a for loop also can't it?

Comment: It could, but the numberes in NASAs gallery aren't sequential so you would pull 404ed images.